# Is it possible to export a C++ member method with C linkage in a DLL?

Tags: c++, c, dll, export, linkage

Consider this in a cpp file:

```
struct someStruct{
    public:
    extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) int sumup();
} someStruct;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int someStruct::sumup()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This does not compile: `error: expected unqualified-id before string constant`
Is it no possible to export a C++ member method with C linkage?

Comment: How do you suppose that would work, calling a member function in C code?

Comment: It *is* possible, just not very pretty, as you'd have to use the decorated name (haven't done it in 15 years though). C++ programmers always had to provide callback functions to C libraries, including ... the Win32 API. Most likely there is a duplicate answer out there

Comment: " C++ programmers always had to provide callback functions to C libraries, including ... the Win32 API" - Not sure what that's got to do with it since member functions can't be used as callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, linkage specifications don't apply to member functions; by [dcl.link]/4:

> [...] A linkage-specification shall occur only in namespace scope (3.3). [...]

But there's even an example in the Standard that relates to your question somewhat, in the same paragraph:

> [...] A C language linkage is ignored in determining the language linkage of the names of class members and the function type of class member functions. [*Example:*
>
> ```
> extern "C" typedef void FUNC_c();
> class C {
>   void mf1(FUNC_c*);      // the name of the function mf1 and the member
>                           // function’s type have C ++ language linkage; the
>                           // parameter has type pointer to C function
>   FUNC_c mf2;             // the name of the function mf2 and the member
>                           // function’s type have C ++ language linkage
>   static FUNC_c* q;       // the name of the data member q has C ++ language
>                           // linkage and the data member’s type is pointer to
>                           // C function
> };
>
> extern "C" {
>   class X {
>     void mf();            // the name of the function mf and the member
>                           // function’s type have C ++ language linkage
>     void mf2(void(*)());  // the name of the function mf2 has C ++ language
>                           // linkage; the parameter has type pointer to
>                           // C function
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> — *end example*]

Answer (score 0):

No.  It doesn't work that way.  It doesn't work at all.  Can't do it.  No way no how.

Comment: You may not have encountered it before, but it's not uncommon to have to pass a callback function to a C library from a C++ application.

Comment: Not member functions.