# Marshaling C/C++ function with callback function in parameter to C#

Tags: c#, c++, callback, marshalling

I have the following in my native code:

```
typedef void (__stdcall * HandlerCallBack)(float);

class ASSIMP_API NewProgressHandler : public ProgressHandler
{
    HandlerCallBack CallBack;
public:
    bool Update(float percentage = -1.f){
        if (CallBack) CallBack (percentage);
        return true;
    }

    void SetCallBack (HandlerCallBack callback) {
        CallBack = callback;
    }
};

void Importer::SetProgressHandlerCallBack (HandlerCallBack CallBack) {
   NewProgressHandler* pNewHandler = new NewProgressHandler ();
   pNewHandler->SetCallBack (CallBack);
   ProgressHandler* pHandler = pNewHandler;
   SetProgressHandler (pHandler);
}
```

I need to call

```
SetProgressHandlerCallBack (HandlerCallBack CallBack)
```

from c# code, so I do the following:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate void HandlerCallBack([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]float percent);

[DllImport("my.dll")]
public static extern void SetProgressHandlerCallBack ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] 
                                                      HandlerCallBack callBack);

public void AssimpCallBack ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]float percent) {
    Debug.Log (percent);
}



void SomeFunction () {
   HandlerCallBack cb = new HandlerCallBack (AssimpCallBack);
   SetProgressHandlerCallBack (cb);
}
```

but I'm getting an exception,

> SetProgressHandlerCallBack
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   ModellInstantiator:SetProgressHandlerCallBack
>   (ModellInstantiator/HandlerCallBack)

and I cant figure out what am I missing.

Comment: What is the exception you are seeing?

Comment: Do you consider a C++\CLI wrapper a possibility? It's a very clean and natural way to evade all that declarative-type marshaling stuff.

Comment: _SetProgressHandlerCallBack
at (wrapper managed-to-native) ModellInstantiator:SetProgressHandlerCallBack (ModellInstantiator/HandlerCallBack)_


that's what I can see.

Answer (score 2):

In your code above the `SetProgressHandlerCallback` function you show looks like this:

```
void Importer::SetProgressHandlerCallBack(...) { ... }
```

There are 2 problems with this, both of which can be explained with a simple Minimum Complete Verifiable Example, I created<sup>*1*</sup> a new Visual Studio solution, containing a C# (WinForms) project and a C++ Dll (unmanaged not C++/CLI).

In the DLL (dllmain.cpp) I placed the following code:

```cpp
typedef void (__stdcall *HandlerCallBack)(float);

extern "C" {

    // extern "C" ignored for C++ classes
    class __declspec(dllexport) TestClass
    {
    public:
        static void CallMeBack(HandlerCallBack callback)
        {
            callback(1.0f);
        }
    };


    void __declspec(dllexport) CallRightBack(HandlerCallBack callback)
    {
        TestClass::CallMeBack(callback);
    }
}
```

You can see the callback signature matching the one you're using, and a static class method and a exported function. Build this, start the Visual Studio command prompt and run

```
dumpbin /exports <dllname>.dll
```

This gives you the exported functions from the DLL, which looks something like this:

```
(Trimmed to just show what we care about)
    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00011082 ??4TestClass@@QEAAAEAV0@$$QEAV0@@Z = @ILT+125(??4TestClass@@QEAAAEAV0@$$QEAV0@@Z)
          2    1 000110E1 ??4TestClass@@QEAAAEAV0@AEBV0@@Z = @ILT+220(??4TestClass@@QEAAAEAV0@AEBV0@@Z)
          3    2 00011069 ?CallMeBack@TestClass@@SAXP6AXM@Z@Z = @ILT+100(?CallMeBack@TestClass@@SAXP6AXM@Z@Z)
          4    3 00011014 CallRightBack = @ILT+15(CallRightBack)
```

You'll notice that the regular global function is exported with its undecorated name, but that the static method is exported *with* a decorated (mangled) name.

Now lets add some code to the C# project and see why this becomes a problem. Add 2 buttons (button1 and button2<sup>*2*</sup>). To the form, I added the following code:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
delegate void HandlerCallbackDelegate(float value);

[DllImport("CppDllTestProj.dll")]
static extern void CallRightBack([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]HandlerCallbackDelegate callback);

[DllImport("CppDllTestProj.dll")]
static extern void CallMeBack([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]HandlerCallbackDelegate callback);

HandlerCallbackDelegate callbackDel;

// in the designer associated with button1
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.callbackDel == null)
    {
        this.callbackDel = new HandlerCallbackDelegate(this.Callback);
    }
    CallRightBack(callbackDel);
}

// in the designer associated with button2
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.callbackDel == null)
    {
        this.callbackDel = new HandlerCallbackDelegate(this.Callback);
    }
    CallMeBack(callbackDel);
}

void Callback(float value)
{
    MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
}
```

Compile, copy the dll into the C# project's build directory, and run. Click button1, the callback is called, and the message box shows up. Click button 2 and the program crashes with the exception:

> Unable to find an entry point named 'CallMeBack' in DLL 'CppDllTestProj.dll'.
>      at ScratchApp.Form1.CallMeBack(HandlerCallbackDelegate callback)
>      at ScratchApp.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in Form1.cs:line 49

Unable to find an entry point named 'CallMeBack' means that it couldn't find a function in that DLL with that name.  If I now change the `CallMeBack` definition in the C# test application to:

```
[DllImport("CppDllTestProj.dll", EntryPoint="?CallMeBack@TestClass@@SAXP6AXM@Z@Z")]
static extern void CallMeBack([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]HandlerCallbackDelegate callback);
```

Recompile, and restart, now both buttons function correctly. (Your mangled/decorated name may look different. Use whatever value you get from dumpbin.)

The root of this problem is that the `extern "c"` storage class specifier is ignored for C++ classes and class members<sup>*3*</sup>.

The other problem which you will have as soon as you fix the above, is this code:

```
void SomeFunction () {
   HandlerCallBack cb = new HandlerCallBack (AssimpCallBack);
   SetProgressHandlerCallBack (cb);
}
```

You'll note that `cb` becomes available for garbage collection the instant that control returns from the call to `SetProgressHandlerCallBack`. Once that delegate is garbage collected any callback will fail. Spectacularly.

---

<sub>*<sup>1</sup>Technically the same project I use for all testing, but I clear the code each time.*

*<sup>2</sup>Creative names, I know.*

*<sup>3</sup>Source: [Is it possible to export a C++ member method with C linkage in a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27441622/5240004)*</sub>